# Adding video codec to Android

Tags: android, video, codec, http-live-streaming, mpeg2-ts

Can someone please explain the steps I need to take in order to add a
new codec to Android?

Also, I would like the codec to be installed as part of an application
installation (or first launch) and NOT as part of a full Android OS
build.

The reason I want to do this is that I have an application that needs
to show a video of a non supported codec (HLS or TS), but I wouldn't
want to build a full blown video player - just integrate with the
existing, built-in, player.

Thanks,
 Alik.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Can someone please explain the steps I need to take in order to add a new codec to Android?

Build your own firmware, or build your own media player (like VLC for Android).

> Also, I would like the codec to be installed as part of an application installation (or first launch) and NOT as part of a full Android OS build.

That is not possible, unless you build your own media player.

> The reason I want to do this is that I have an application that needs to show a video of a non supported codec (HLS or TS), but I wouldn't want to build a full blown video player - just integrate with the existing, built-in, player.

VLC for Android is due out (at least for some phones) shortly, so it may be able to play your format.

Comment: Why is it not possible? I read some things regarding OMX and thought I'd just implement the correct codec classes, put them in the right place, connect them to stagefright and I would have a new codec implementation with the default player. The problem is that I don't see documentation for each step in the way.

Comment: @kilaka: Except for the minor matter that unless you are building your own firmware, you cannot "put them in the right place", since you do not have write access to wherever that is.

Answer (score 1):

I think it maybe possible to add custom codec(though I have not tried) by referring to the android developer page [Adding custom codec to android](https://source.android.com/devices/media.html).

You can try out adding your codec through openMAX IL layer then call up the android media player to play it(I believe vlc has done in this way but uses its own player). The awesome player, the android default player, just fetch a list of codecs available through openMAX API and if there is a codec, it plays. So it is worth to try adding your codec during initialization of your app, and call up media player.